# codeigniter pagination links exceeded

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have this pagination on my website. My problem is the links below exceed too much. For example, it goes to page 228, and there is no data in there anymore.

Here's my controller code below

```
 public function index(){
    $this->data['title'] = 'Programs | Spring Rain Global Consultancy Inc';
    $this->data['active_menu'] = 'programs';
    $this->data['active_link'] = 'program_menu';

    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url(). "programs/index";
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->am->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $choice = $config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page'];
    $total_rows = $config['total_rows'] = $this->am->record_count();
    $config['num_links'] = round($choice);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $this->data['fecth_activities'] = $this->am->getAllActivities($config['per_page'], $page);
    $this->data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($this->data['links']);
    //echo "</pre>";

    $this->load->view('pages/header', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('templates/programs', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('pages/footer');
    $this->load->view('pages/footer_below');
  }
```

Here's my model below

```
class Activities_model extends CI_Model{
  public function record_count(){
    return $this->db->count_all('seminars');
  }

  public function getAllActivities($start, $limit){
    return $this->db->limit($start, $limit)
                    ->select('seminars.id,
                        seminars.category, 
                        seminars.thumb, 
                        seminars_category.id,
                        seminars_category.category,
                        seminars_category.url,
                        seminars_category.date,
                        seminars_category.abvr'
                      )
                    ->from('seminars')
                    ->join('seminars_category', 'seminars_category.id = seminars.category')
                    ->where('seminars.id  =', 1)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 7)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 12)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 20)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 24)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 29)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 77)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 84)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 103)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 157)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 187)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 234)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 241)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 308)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 314)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 390)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 407)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 414)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 429)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 455)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 462)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 511)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 537)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 573)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 591)
                    ->or_where('seminars.id =', 641)
                    ->order_by('seminars_category.date', 'DESC')
                    ->get()->result_object();
    $query = $this->db->get('seminars');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $data[] = $row;
      }
      return $data;
    }
    return false;

  }

}
```

This thing works but only the links below exceeds to 228.

Comment: you are taking count of all elements in the database...... also put where conditions on the __record_count__ function, it may solve ur problem

Comment: ahh like the getAllActivities() ???/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
class Activities_model extends CI_Model {

    public function record_count() {

        $this->db->where('seminars.id  =', 1)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 7)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 12)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 20)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 24)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 29)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 77)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 84)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 103)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 157)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 187)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 234)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 241)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 308)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 314)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 390)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 407)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 414)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 429)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 455)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 462)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 511)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 537)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 573)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 591)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 641)
                > from('seminars');
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function getAllActivities($start, $limit) {
        return $this->db->limit($start, $limit)
                        ->select('seminars.id,
                            seminars.category, 
                            seminars.thumb, 
                            seminars_category.id,
                            seminars_category.category,
                            seminars_category.url,
                            seminars_category.date,
                            seminars_category.abvr'
                        )
                        ->from('seminars')
                        ->join('seminars_category', 'seminars_category.id = seminars.category')
                        ->where('seminars.id  =', 1)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 7)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 12)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 20)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 24)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 29)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 77)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 84)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 103)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 157)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 187)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 234)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 241)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 308)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 314)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 390)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 407)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 414)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 429)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 455)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 462)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 511)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 537)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 573)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 591)
                        ->or_where('seminars.id =', 641)
                        ->order_by('seminars_category.date', 'DESC')
                        ->get()->result_object();
        $query = $this->db->get('seminars');
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

You are taking count of all elements in the database......put where conditions on the **record_count** function, it may solve ur problem

Comment: thanks a lot men!! now it works! its all the count_all_results() Merry Christmas! then!

Comment: Since I have no way to contact you, @Pranavc, please stop doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3664436).